# The Go code does not compile: undefined: revel.EmptyPlugin

Tags: go

Me and a few friends are writing a server using golang (revel) and had a database implemented just a few weeks ago. Then suddenly everything just stopped working and the go compiler can't find my import files. That includes EmptyPlugin as well as RegisterPlugin.

We are all pretty new so this is probably a pretty simple fix. I have checked my github.com/robfig/revel folder, and there is no file called EmptyPlugin. But that is probably a misunderstanding from my side :P.

By commenting the lines revel.EmptyPlugin and revel.RegisterPlugin(DbPlugin{}) everything works as it should.

```
package controllers

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/bmizerany/pq"
    "github.com/robfig/revel"
    "log"
    "time"
    //"strconv"
)

type DbPlugin struct {
    revel.EmptyPlugin
}



func init() {
    revel.RegisterPlugin(DbPlugin{})
}


var db *sql.DB 
var err error
```

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: Wait...it works if you remove EmptyPlugin?  Then...I *think* you've got your fix...

Comment: The exact error message is  "gocode/src/myproject/app/controllers/DBrevel.go does not compile: undefined: revel.EmptyPlugin"

Comment: How is it a fix to remove the code? Then how am I supposed to connect to my database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to compiling using the latest and recently updated version of Revel: https://github.com/robfig/revel.

However, it appears that your code was written for this older version of Revel: https://github.com/robfig/revel/tree/dev.

Update your code to the latest version of Revel.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what it was. I find the lack of good examples pretty disturbing but i got it to work somehow with a pretty ugly solution. Do you know what happened to their old function OnAppStart()? I want one of my function (the "connect to DB"-part) to run once everytime i call a function inside that document.